# Что такое schema в БД?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Что такое schema в postgreSQL? Её надо создавать сразу после создания БД? Это логическое устройство таблиц, наполнения, прав и т.д. И тогда может быть много схем и они могут использовать общие таблицы?

Comment: @Мелкий писал ответ на этот вопрос тут https://qna.habr.com/answer?answer_id=1423551#answers_list_answer

Comment: и тут теперь будет

Comment: @Мелкий может ли в одной схеме быть таблица из другой?

Comment: @Venot таблица всегда относится к одной схеме. в другой схеме может быть другая таблица с тем же именем, что в первой и это будут разные таблицы

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> [Schemas](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-schemas.html) are analogous to directories at the operating system level, except that schemas cannot be nested.

Схемы - это дополнительный уровень структурирования объектов базы. Похоже на директории в файловой системе или пространства имён (`namespace`) в программировании. Но не могут быть вложенными.

Пользуясь аналогией с файловой системой и вебом: есть файлы стилей CSS, какие-то JS. Ничто не мешает их все размещать в корневой директории веб-сервера. Но обычно их размещают всё-таки в поддиректориях для собственного удобства.

После создания новой базы у вас будет предопределённая схема `public` с правами для создания новых объектов для всех пользователей. Что делать дальше - решение разработчика схемы этой базы, проигнорировать схемы и размещать всё в `public`, структурировать как-либо по схемам, можно удалить `public` схему даже.

Делать таблицы:

- `users`
- `user_settings`
- `user_favorites`
- `blog_posts`
- `blog_comments`

Или же:

- `users`
- `users.settings`
- `users.favorites`
- `blog.posts`
- `blog.comments`

Самой базе без разницы. Схемы - это логический уровень, как названия таблиц.

Большинство проектов схемы не используют.

---

Права: у схем есть права `create` - кто может создавать новые объекты, и `usage` - кто может обращаться к объектам в той схеме. Поэтому может быть удобно для разработчиков сделать отдельную схему `user_tmp` и исключить её из бекапов, а в остальные схемы не давать прав `create` - тем самым форсируя, что таблицы приложения проходят через обычную принятую у вас процедуру миграций.

---

Для полноты картины: схемы `public` может и не быть, если она была удалена в базе, которая указанна в `template` опции `create database`